# Collection View inside Table View Cell Slow Scroll Performance

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have checked, tried many solutions on stackoverflow and from many website I searched.

My problem: I have a collection view inside table view cell. My data must be loaded 1 time in table view ( viewdidload).

When I pass data to collection view inside table cells, it's not appear because I need to reload collection view again.

So I do: Data -> inside cellforrow of table view -> Pass to collection view -> cell.collectionView.reloadData()

**This cause a problem about scroll performance:** collectionView.reloadData() call over and over again when I scroll ( this right because of resuable cells architecture of table view.

Here my code in cellforrow of tableView:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SubCategoryCellID) as! SubCategoryCell
        if isFetched {
            cell.shimmeringView.isShimmering = false
            cell.shimmeringImageView.isHidden = true
            cell.shimmeringView.isHidden = true
            cell.listLocation = nestedSubLocation[indexPath.item]
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        }else {
            return cell
        }
```

*Solutions I tried:* 
+ Create static cells and get cells to display in cellForRow (it's totally fix scroll performance but I think it not good for memory management and it's not working if parent is collection view).
 + Reload data when scroll stop: it's still need to reloadData in loading first time and wrong data if I dont reload again.

To fix that, anyone have an clever approach to fix scroll performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code after `cell.collectionView.reloadData()`

```
cell.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.zero, animated: false)
```

Comment: Great solution, could you explain how this actually works?

Comment: @inokey This method scrolls the content view so that the area defined by rect is just visible inside the scroll view. If the area is already visible, the method does nothing. [Refer this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible?language=objc)

Comment: i've tried your solution but it only removed the lag in simulator. Test device still couldn't process this fast enough. But my problem was deep inside the collection view, when building the cell itself, so I guess your solution will work for most of light-weight situations. Thanks for the reply!